# Container with `margin 0: auto` and children with `display:grid` clashing

Tags: css, css-grid

So I have a container as such:

```
.container{
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}
```

And inside the container, I have another child container/element which is a grid:

```
.child{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 15px;
}
```

Now for some reason, the child is causing the `margin: 0 auto` on the container to act weirdly: for example, at one time the margin on the left/right sides could be 280px, and other times it could be 297px, even if the screen width has not changed.

If I take out the following line from the `.child`,

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(320px, 1fr));`

...it works as expected, and the margin doesn't change.

I spent hours trying to figure this out with no luck, any ideas as to what could be happening here?

Comment: Tried to reproduce the problem. But I couldn't. Don't see the changing margins. https://jsfiddle.net/cgLdkfj3/

Comment: Please post the actual code including the smallest set of CSS and HTML IN your question that reproduces the issue so that we might help you fix it.